# convert yes or no to boolean format for a special code

Tags: c

I need to make a program which asks the user to enter either y or n as boolean values: here is what I mean:

```
#include<stdbool.h>
#define bool p
#define y 1
#define n 0
do {
    /*some code*/ 

    printf("do you want to continue?! y/n");
    scanf("%B",&p);
}while (p=='y');
```

I had been struggling a lot with it, so please help me!

Comment: Read the character, check if it's y or n, and set a boolean variable appropriately

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of errors in the posted code. `#define bool p` is wrong, since it redefines `bool` as a macro for `p`. Similarly, `#define y 1` and `#define n 0` do not do what you think, but define macros that replace occurrences of `y` and `n` in the source code with `1` and `0`, respectively.

There is no `%B` conversion specifier in standard C (or any other C that I am aware of). And `&p` takes the address of an undefined variable.

Consider defining a variable `cont` as a `bool`, and changing its value based on user input to control your loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
    bool cont = false;
    char input;

    do {
        printf("Do you want to continue (y/n)? ");
        scanf(" %c", &input);

        if (input == 'y' || input == 'Y') {
            cont = true;
        } else {
            cont = false;
        }
    } while (cont);

    return 0;
}
```

Here, `cont` is only `true` when the user enters `y` or `Y`. Also note the space at the beginning of the `scanf()` format string: `" %c"`. This causes `scanf()` to skip over leading whitespaces, including newlines, that may be in the input stream (such as those left behind by previous calls to `scanf()`.

Note that better code would check the value returned by `scanf()`, or might use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` instead of `scanf()`, more carefully validating the input.

Sample interaction:

```
Do you want to continue (y/n)? Y
Do you want to continue (y/n)? Y
Do you want to continue (y/n)? N
```